# Insert fields in File record using Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have below code in Groovy. Basically what I'm trying is to read the set of Input records and merge them into 1 or more records with common key combination.

The Key combination is as shown below. After reading the input file, I have written the key and fields into HashMap ( see code). But now I need to check the key in the input file , if the key is seen then I have write the output record otherwise I just need to write a output record as without merging. My questions

what is the command to insert a field in  Output record ?.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


for( int i = 0; i < dataContext.getDataCount(); i++ ) {
  InputStream is = dataContext.getStream(i);
  Properties props = dataContext.getProperties(i);
  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 


 /* This is how to declare HashMap */
  def forcastMap = [:]

 String Key;   
 String Shipfrom = "";
 String Item = "";
 String Fcast = "";
 String Shipto = "";
 String Planned_Arrival_Date = "";
 String Qty = "";
 String PrevKey = "";

 List<String> line = null

 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
 {
        if(line.length() > 20) //Make sure it is a data line so we can do substring manipulation
        {    
           Shipfrom = line.substring(35,12)  
           Item = line.substring(50,50)
           Fcast = line.substring(10,50)
           Shipto = line.substring(75,10)
           Planned_Arrival_Date = line.substring(85,8)
           Qty = line.substring(90,12)
           Key = (Shipfrom + Item + Fcast + Shipto)
           forcastMap.put(Key,Planned_Arrival_Date,Qty)
           if key != PrevKey {

           }
         }

     }      

 //dataContext.storeStream(is, props);

}
```